# Limit of a sequence. Help finding the epsilon

Tags: real-analysis

So I'm trying to find the limit of the sequence $n$/($n^2$ + $1$). So I need to prove that

$|$ $n$ / ($n^2$ + 1) | < ε .

I'm having trouble finding the n for when this is true. How do I simply the equation so that I can find n in terms of ε? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac{n}{n^2+1} \leq \dfrac{n}{n^2}=1/n.$ So choose $n$ such that $ n \geq 1/ \epsilon$

Comment: So is it a general strategy to do this kind of comparison to something that we can find an $n$ for?

Comment: I think you meant $n>1/\epsilon$...

Comment: @rawrPanda: Yes. These are the tricks to keep in mind.

Comment: @voldemort: Right, I'm sorry.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: No I mean $n \geq \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$ ;-)

Comment: @voldemort: Are there any other "tricks" to keep in mind for these kinds of problems?

Comment: @rawrPanda: Generally I have seen comparisons work great in these scenarios. However, no such trick directly comes to my mind. Keep doing problems; hopefully you shall see what to apply even better that I will ever know.

Comment: @voldemort: I just thought of something. How do we know that just because $n$/$n^2$ is larger and has a limit of 0 that the original sequence also has the same limit?

Comment: @rawrPanda: Sandwich theorem/ squeeze theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem